# How can I stream music from SoundCloud in a node-webkit app using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, soundcloud, node-webkit

I am trying to use the hosted SoundCloud JS SDK in a node-webkit desktop app.

It seems like a lot of links in the API use //... instead of http://... and node-webkit gets confused because of this. It tries to find the resource at file://... I want to be able to stream music into a custom player using the SDK's streaming features.

How can I do one of these:

1. Trick node-webkit into looking at http:// instead of file://
2. Use JavaScript to stream music without the SDK into my own player with JavaScript

Should I just download and edit the SDK and include it in the app?

I would really love to use the SDK because it makes my life simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, yeah I guess this was never thought of at the time. Personally, I'd go with 'forking' and specifying the urls (I'd also choose 'https').

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm new to this, so it'll take me a while to figure out how to edit that SDK on GitHub. I'll get around to it. Meanwhile, until any of my edits make it into the hosted version, am I allowed to distribute a modified version of the SDK inside my app?

Comment: It's MIT licensed, so you can definitely distribute it, just as long as you also distribute the copyright license along with it. (See here https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-javascript/blob/master/LICENSE)